# Java compiler behaviour question

Tags: java

I have an interface & its implementation class in the same package. I using javac in commandline to compile them. I am able to compile the interface class successfully, but when try to compile the implementation class after compiling the interface class, I get the error - Symbol not found. However, as both the interface & its implementation are in the same folder, if I do a Javac *. I am able to compile both of them .

Can someone help me understand this behaviour ? Thanks for your time

Comment: Can you clarify a bit ? You say that you cannot "compile the implementation class after compiling the interface class", but it works if you "do a Javac". 

"Doing a javac" is what most people would call "compiling the class". So can you give us the actual command lines you are using ?

Comment: It might help to show exactly what commands you are typing, and the exact full text of the error message(s).

Answer (score 5):

The Java compiler looks for packages by way of a file name convention, `a.b.c.Interface` is interpreted as look for the interface in `a/b/c/Interface.class`

If you run javac from the root of your classpath, the compiler will find your interface. I.e. If your package is at `D:\sources\a\b\c`, start javac in `D:\sources` and compile `a\b\c\Impl.java`

Answer (score 1):

You must compile both files at the same time or add the `.class` file of the first run in the classpath of `javac`. `javac` doesn't try to be smart and doesn't search your harddisk for files which might resolve missing symbols. If you don't pass something in, it won't find it.